# How to copy a file from Linux System to Windows system using Java program?

Tags: java, filesystems

How to copy a file from Linux System to Windows system using Java program?
Thanks for your help.
I want to copy file from linux : /inet/apps/test.java to windows  System1: C:\apps\test
We can use following program to copy

```
    public static void copyFiles(String fromFile, String toFile ){
     FileInputStream from = null;
        FileOutputStream to = null;
        try {
          from = new FileInputStream(fromFile);
          to = new FileOutputStream(toFile);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          int bytesRead;

          while ((bytesRead = from.read(buffer)) != -1)
            to.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); // write
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
          if (from != null)
            try { from.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
          if (to != null)try {to.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
        }     
 }
```

This program is running on linux.
so `fromFile = /inet/apps/test`. What will be the `toFile` path. If i use simply `C:\apps\test` then how applicaiton recognise the target as `System1`.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate if you want an answer my friend. Perhaps you should read Jon Skeet's Guide to asking questions on SO: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Java makes no diffeence between Windows and Linux files. So, as long as you have access to both filesystem in the computer your java program is running, you can just copy them.

Comment: I am running java file in linux,. So unixFile Path will be /inet/apps/test.java. How to specify Windows file >Sorry it may be basic.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you are asking about some
   properties for the program.

   In that case the properties, should
   be configurable. You can keep the
   properties file in the same
   directory as your Java program or in
   the class path.
2. The property file might look like :

   ```
       windows.filepath = C:\user\somefile.txt
       unix.filepath = /inet/apps/test.txt
   ```

   So when you port environments. You
   don't need to change the properties.

   If you are asking about how to port
   test.java to windows, then just copy
   the file to JAVA_HOME directory on
   windows and then you are good to go.
3. Or If you have a Dual boot system.
   You can access your [linux drive
   from windows](http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows), but not the other
   way around.

Comment: Thank you. if i use windows.filepath = C:\user\somefile.txt.in this way how application recognises the target system. Please see my edit in Question

Answer (score 0):

If the Unix system has the Window file system cross-mounted (e.g. via an SMB share), you should be able to find the Unix pathname that corresponds to the Windows destination and copy as you are currently doing.

Otherwise, you will need to use a file transfer protocol of some kind to copy the file.

There's no Java magic that allows you to magically write files to a different computer.  The operating system has to be set up to allow this to happen.

**FOLLOW UP** - you asked:

> I have no thought about the magic. So my question was how to copy a file from Windows to Linux. Normally we do FTP on unix Without mounting or we use FileZilla tool to transfer happens. Here if we want to do same thing though java then how to do that?

I don't know how I can say this differently to make you understand, but here goes:

Your choices in Java are basically the same:

- You can use FTP.  For example on the destination machine, turn pathname of the source file into a "ftp://..." URL, and use `java.net.URL.connect()` to pull it.  There are probably 3rd-party Java libraries that you can use to "push" the file to a FTP server.
- If your OS is setup with the file systems cross-mount, you can do a regular file copy, much as your code does.
- You can use `java.lang.System.exec(...)` to run some Windows specific command line utility to do the copying.

In all cases, you will need to figure out how to map pathnames between the Windows and Linux worlds.

Comment: What is the meaning of " you will need to use a file transfer protocol of some kind to copy the file". Is this through UNIX box? I need to this through java program. Please help

Comment: Are'nt the files on the same machine?

Comment: @Vanchinathan Chandrasekaran - If so, how would you explain the phrase: *"... then how applicaiton recognise the target as System1."* ?  I think the root issue is that the OP *thinks* that Java can magically copy files from one machine to another.

Comment: I have no thought about the magic. So my question was how to copy a file from Windows to Linux. Normally we do FTP  on unix Without mounting or we use FileZilla tool to transfer happens. Here if we want to do same thing though java then how to do that?

Comment: I confused with the answer that, java does not have any difference between them then i expanded my question with IO transfer

Comment: I haven't posted my question clearly with my confusion. Thank you for all of your time

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `copy()` method of the `java.nio.file.Files` class, of course we assume that your application can access both the path on Linux and Windows either by mapping the folders or something similar. For example

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(source), Paths.get(destination), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```